# Android service && app

Tags: android, android-service

I'm just reading up on the use of services to keep an app alive in the background.

A few things are not quite clear to me.

1: Once a service has started, does it stay alive when the main app gets destroyed by Android? (I know it does with OnPause() and OnStop() )

2: If anything is declared in memory for the service, is there a way to access this as well from my app?? (EG service just records the GPS to see if you're moving or standing still. from the main app I want to see how much of each is recorded while the main app was inactive)

I know these are fairly general questions, I'm just reading up on this part of Android programming, and would like to modify a program in the near future. So I have no code to go with the question yet

Thanks,

BBBwex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once a service has started, does it stay alive when the main app gets destroyed by Android?

An app does not get destroyed. Activities get destroyed. Apps have their process terminated.

A service will run in the process until:

- there are no more bound connections (i.e., via `bindService()`) and
- if the service was started with `startService()`, it was stopped with `stopService()` or `stopSelf()`

Of course, once the process is terminated, the service (and everything else) is gone.

> If anything is declared in memory for the service, is there a way to access this as well from my app?

Your service is part of your app. I am going to assume here that by "app" you mean "activity".

Your service has any number of ways of publishing information in ways that an activity can monitor and use, including:

- Service writes the data to a `ContentProvider`, which updates the activity via a `Loader` or `ContentObserver`
- Service sends messages to the activity, via `LocalBroadcastManager`, a third-party message bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), a `Messenger` tied to a `Handler`, etc.
- Service stores a cache of data in a static data member, which the activity reads (or perhaps polls)
- The activity simply reads the data out of whatever persistent data store the service uses (e.g., `SharedPreferences`) as needed
- Etc.

Comment: Also you can consider using EventBus(https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) as an alternative to Otto. It's benchmarks look remarkably better.

Comment: yeah, sorry, newb thing... meant to say activity, not app. thanks, Looks like I need to do a bit more of learning up on this, try out a few things, but in general I did get my answer here... Staying sober the weekend, got to learn a bit more. Thanks!!